# Go install failing while installing k8s 'Kind'

Tags: go, ubuntu, kubernetes, go-modules, kind

While trying to install Kind [using these instructions](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/), I am getting this error:

```
can't load package: package sigs.k8s.io/kind@v0.20.0: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
```

I'm not sure what this means? I have installed go, and $GOPATH seems to be set (basically to `/home/myusername/go`).

I am trying to learn kubernetes and I would like to use kind for creating a cluster. I don't know if it matters, but I am on WSL2. Docker is installed directly on linux (and docker daemon is running).

Comment: are you working inside your gopath and do you have gomodules enabled?

Comment: @RickRackow No, I'm  not inside the gopath folder. I don't know what you mean by having 'gomodules enabled' so probably not? This isn't a go development project - I am not using, importing or creating modules, so...

Comment: **HEY ALL - IT APPEARS THEY HAVE ANOTHER INSTALLATION PAGE HERE** with a different method which seems to work: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#installation